# How can we create a pytorch model with multiple outputs based on conditions?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to make a multi-output model where I have two different conditions. The model should be something like this

```
def forward:
    if condition1 and condition2:
         something_1
    if condition1:
         something_2
    if condition2:
         something_3

    o1 = classifier_output(something_1)
    o2 = classifier_output(something_2)
    o3 = classifier_output(something_3)

    return{o1, o2, o3}
```

The main question that I have here is the following there will be times when one of the if conditions will not be called when we only have true for either condition 1 or condition 2. In that scenario how will be extract output classifier's logits? Will the return also be part of conditional statements based on how many outputs it get ?

Answer (score 0):

Your first condition is with an **and**, so if you have either condition 1 or 2 to False, you will only be getting one if statement running. In that case, you will want to set some default value to the something_x other wise it will clash, or you can just put the o1,o2,o3 into the if statement and give some init value for the o1,o2,o3 above the if statements.

Comment: Thank You. I also want to add that if only one condition is true then I don't want the weights of the network to be updating the conditions that we got from other branches. So, in that case will the return be also part of the conditional block?

Comment: I don't think the return is going to be part of the condition block.

Comment: I see. Thank you this helps a little. I have another question that is bugging me right now. Let's say that we initiate some values for o1, o2 and o2 and then later we realise that the branches from which we get o1 and o2 and not used. wouldn't that hurt my model if initialization of these values are wrong. So basically what I am trying to ask is how would you initiate these values ?

Comment: what about you make different return statements in each if statement. I think that might be a better solution to this.